# How can I rotate the camera when the mouse roll over (no click & drag)?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I use A-Frame for displaying a 360 image. By default the camera rotates when you click and drag it. But I want that A-Frame let the the camera rotates when mouse rolls over.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-sky src="SAM_100_2981.jpg" rotation="0 -100 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: What do you mean "play" an image?

Comment: yes... play mean "image move"

as cnn .... ==> http://edition.cnn.com/vr